# From which translation version do people usually quote the bible?

Tags: bible

People speaking English around the world like to quote the Bible, e.g. verses in Psalm, Matthew, and Romans. Which translation versions do they usually quote? Is it correct that they only quote KJV version,  not ESV, NIV, ...?

Comment: Of course not! Why would you think people only quote from the KJV??

Answer (score 2):

**Which Church does one attend?**

We see quotes from many versions of the Bible on this Stack. Though I have no evidence to prove it, I suspect that the reasons any one person might choose one version over another include:

- The version of the Bible they grew up with.
- The version used by the church or congregation they currently frequent.
- The version used if (and therefore when) they were introduced to Christianity.

But what's curious is that, I suspect, many of us quote from a preferred version despite having access to many. I personally tend to quote from KJV, but I have six Bibles and I've used them all for various reasons (and I've found enlightenment from all of them).

If you feel that you predominantly see KJV quotations vs. any others, that might identify the group of people you most commonly receive quotes from more than a global preference. Considering the number of Catholics in the English-speaking world, it's surprising you haven't seen more quotes from Douay-Rheims or NAB, thus my wonder about the groups you've frequented.

Comment: I think the answer to your last question is that the OP has been looking at Protestant sites on the internet. Off the internet, there are still English speakers who call it the Authorised Version (AV_.